# Write an interpreter for simplified 33

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

[33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33) is a simple esolang I created. You may have seen me use it in a few questions. You're not going to be writing a full interpreter. The interpreter you will be writing is for a simplified version of 33.

This simplified 33 has two numeric registers: the accumulator and the counter. The accumulator holds all the post-arithmetic values, the counter is where numbers in the program come from. Both registers are initialized to 0.

```
0-9 | Appends the digit to the counter
a   | Adds the counter to the accumulator
m   | Subtracts the counter from the accumulator
x   | Multiplies the accumulator by the counter
d   | Divides the accumulator by the counter
r   | Divides the accumulator by the counter, but stores the remainder in the accumulator
z   | Sets the counter to 0
c   | Swaps the accumulator and counter
-----
p   | Outputs the current value of the accumulator as an ASCII character
o   | Outputs the current value of the accumulator as a formatted decimal number
i   | Outputs a newline character (0x0a)
-----
P   | Stores the ASCII value of the next character read in the accumulator
O   | Stores the next integer read into the accumulator
-----
n   | Skips the next instruction if the accumulator is not 0
N   | Skips the next instruction if the accumulator is 0
g   | Skips the next instruction if the accumulator is less than or equal to 0
G   | Skips the next instruction if the accumulator is greater than 0
h   | Skips the next instruction if the accumulator is greater than or equal to 0
H   | Skips the next instruction if the accumulator is less than 0
```

### Test cases

```
Program / Input -> Output
2o          -> 0
25co        -> 25
1a0aoi      -> 11 (trailing newline)
Oo / 42     -> 42
Op / 42     -> *
1cNoo       -> 11
no          -> 0
Ogo / 2     -> 2
Ogoi / -4   -> (newline)
50a         -> (no output)
On12co / 12 -> 2
```

### Clarifications

- The input to your interpreter will be a valid simplified 33 program.
- The input may be given in any [acceptable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- The output may be given in any acceptable format.
- When dividing, truncate any decimal places.
- A trailing newline is acceptable, but it must be consistent; as in, if there's an `i` at the end of the program, it should have two trailing newlines.
- The accumulator and counter must be able to hold at least a signed byte (-128 to 127)
- You may assume that the `p` instruction will never be given when the accumulator has an invalid ASCII character in it.
- You may assume the `O` instruction will never be given unless there is a valid integer string (such as `3`, `-54`, `+23`) left in the input.

Comment: How does `O` work?

Comment: @tsh Yes. I'll update that.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It reads the integer in the same format that `o` outputs it

Comment: @TheOnlyMrCat If the remaining input is `x-13`, will `O` skip the `x` and read the `-13`? Or can we assume that there will always be an integer right where the `O` reads the input?

Comment: What is acceptable format for an integer input the interpreter must handle? Will `+03` be valid input for integer?

Comment: ```+``` and ```-``` are not valid commands in 33, and 33 only handles positive integers.

Comment: @A_ `The accumulator and counter must be able to hold at least a signed byte (-128 to 127)`

Comment: I believe that is internally, not externally.

Comment: ```N12``` should skip the ```1``` command, since ```1``` and ```2``` are separate commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98486/discussion-between-tsh-and-a).

Comment: @TheOnlyMrCat In the official 33 interpreter, trying to read an integer containing letters is invalid. You need to make the challenge self-contained and explain what an interpreter should do with this input.

Comment: How does `p` behave if the accumulator is negative?

Comment: the example `1Noo` should output `0` not `11`.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 264 bytes

```javascript
S=>I=>[...S].map(s=>K?K=0:1/s?C=+(C+s):eval("A*=C;[A,C]=[C,A];K=!A;;K=A;K=A>0;A%=C;K=A<=0;A=A/C|0;I=I.replace(/-?\\d+/,n=>(A=+n,''));K=A>=0;O+=A;K=A<0;A+=C;C=0;;[A]=B(I[0]),I=I.slice(1);O+=`\n`;O+=B([A]);A-=C".split`;`[B(s)[0]*73%378%22]),A=C=K=0,O='',B=Buffer)&&O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJfb5swFMXf@RRepNR2@U9bdQq9RATtgUUqD3kkSFgUMiZqI0wqTds@e2YT2B4WJMwxPr9zr8Hf2QeT1dD2o83FW31p4HKAKIUodxznUDjvrCcSov12D97Gd@U2AZMkpqSb@oN1ZBXfQxLmsZUUkCdWXIR7@BSHaoz1HXlhvFYGJV9AaYjd5JcXppA6Q913rKqJa2@PxzfTtThEJAaTWxhTOsGKyMxr0IuCTRWUqHeqXAE7kuZeQS0dJbtWBflUu8sjL/VzR5SLhrENycqRfdeOZVjmOyKpwu6fH9YPz5/XQaASYkhAbc7KAGNrB7tz09QDvbvLLmMtx4rJGgEqjUCg@TKCp2qeGD7zmGgnmQnkosdgkv1f6VevQhj8H5ydtC@YZau0/YiMJ48t69wPKm3xA2SUhrE04YxD@07odS8EHzmmTiOGL6z6RrqWqyYj9NNAqBJcjiiX4jxUtYVa3p9HtQGMCzVq45JgR1h/i2XqqrzpZ@sgOVej4ZwoutrpxImsDlPuZmWhr4fs1ZHKx09t84NcC94gUKpbuEFMrd0AsvN4G2iWIgv6H4ttrA9WzUYSeHr5Nw0vfwA)

Saved ~20 bytes, thanks to Arnauld's magic integer modulus.

Comment: [253 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY3BboMwEES/hUgkNjbgJK2CYhZkfOLEgSMgYSVGoqIU4TSn/jtdLrur2Zk3X@Zt3GMdl1c4/zztNsBWQ1ZCRgoofofBrpTUNPo2C3GQ1VADgCdycXfpZ5Jr0MFZMBd@JHf7NhM5qAC0bBTXHTSaq056SkoPh8qEVD4@VQp4gYr1n5AllNFql8k8LInDvG2fLOYztitgMz@dKMUg@isGiEgxyBChUcGSDgpSNqKjfMe4aUTIme7evp37fRcEXYgIQR8it0zjq5d944Lb1b/eEv9ywawCxPEKsOx4rLbtHw) by converting the input to a buffer right away, re-using `S` as the result of the previous instruction and using a strict comparison with `true`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Lua 5.3, 342 bytes

Code is provided as a cmdline argument, input is provided via stdin.

```lua
H=string.char R=io.read A=0 C=0 i=1 s=...while i<=#s do
b=s:byte(i)d=H(b)i=i+(({H=A<0,G=A>0,N=A==0,g=A<=0,h=A>=0,n=A~=0})[d]and 2or
1)io.write(({i='\n',o=A|0,p=H(A%255)})[d]or'')A,C=d=='O'and R'n'or d=='P'and
R(1):byte()or d=='d'and A//C or d=='r'and A%C or({a=A+C,c=C,m=A-C,x=A*C})[d]or
A,b>=48 and b<58 and b-48+C*10or({c=A,z=0})[d]or C end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 355 bytes

```julia
p=print
function f(s,a=0,c=0,i=1)
for x=s
z=findfirst(==(x),"amxdrzcpoiPOnNgGhH0123456789")
y=z-9
i<1&&(i=1;continue)
z<6 ? a=(+,-,*,÷,%)[z](a,c) :
z<7 ? c=0 :
z<8 ? ((a,c)=(c,a)) :
z<9 ? p(Char(a)) :
y<1 ? p(a) :
y<2 ? p("\n") :
y<3 ? a=0+read(stdin,UInt8) :
y<4 ? a=parse(Int,readline()) :
y<10 ? (!=,==,<=,>,>=,<)[y-3](a,0)&&(i=0) :
c=10c+y-10
end
end
```

Program provided as an argument, eg `f("2o")`, input taken from `stdin`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDLTsMwELz7K0IkqjV1JDtNXzQLBw7ApeXCqXCwnEeNihMlqZTkx/gAPiw4jwrJq52dWY/X@3U5aynqrssxL7SpSHIxqtKZcRIomUTOlA2NgpIkK5waS9Jiok2U6KKsABFqylz5XUdFq/JMvx3MPn0@vXDhL4Llar3ZupQ02HpbokMxm4G12qnMVNpcYkracOU8OhJhzjx2x35/2C09tp8gmaLOvZXXVrYTDHhjMQwSgmKSjh1by@bwdJIFjFQTioGSY@EPhfth3LFeDA/yeRHLCMoq0oa9v5pqM6rBoOayKGOwLOu7ztrEcLXm/RA3yBBZiOyBPdhMj4236IfmdPgh73sVCq7mjSc4iU3UR5dCSR10wK6W7oZ1n401Jim4fuaOeakmJCSXmR7xYeIO@aSpfTZR5iql/2C6teRyoozwe9su8Ik9PvECIvw/)